# How to make a sticky element with its own scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap

I've a problem with a project idea. When page starts there should be a window with a moving object when you scroll down, after you hit bottom this element should disaper and you should see the begining of the page.

In this project I also use gsap, for effects and section jumping, which is also needed.

Here comes the questions.

1.I cant create a smooth scrool at the begining of the window, because gsap section jumping gives a  uneven scrooling which is ok, bu only after the first block closes, it chouldnt work all the time. Can I init gsap after first block closes ?
2.Other problem is that when i scrool all the element scrools down and when opacity drops to 0 it show middle of the page, which is bad, because it should show the begining of it.

Here is a rough codepen.

https://codepen.io/v1gil/pen/gOqmgaN

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).on("scroll", function () {
    var obj = $(".before-element");
    var currY = $(window).scrollTop();
    var postHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollHeight = obj.height();
    var scrollPercent = 0;
    scrollPercent = (currY / (scrollHeight - postHeight)) * 100 + 30;
    if (scrollPercent > 30 && scrollPercent < 100)
      $("div.moving-element").css("min-width", scrollPercent + "%");
    if (scrollPercent > 100) {
      $(".before-element ").addClass("finished");
      $("html:not(.movement-finished)").scrollTop(0);
      $("div.moving-element").css("min-width", "100%");
      $("html").addClass("movement-finished");
    }
  });
});
let mm = gsap.matchMedia();
mm.add("(min-width: 768px)", () => {
  mm.revert();

  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger, ScrollToPlugin);

  let panels = gsap.utils.toArray(".panel"),
    observer = ScrollTrigger.normalizeScroll(true),
    scrollTween;

  // on touch devices, ignore touchstart events if there's an in-progress tween so that touch-scrolling doesn't interrupt and make it wonky
  document.addEventListener(
    "touchstart",
    (e) => {
      if (scrollTween) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      }
    },
    { capture: true, passive: false }
  );

  function goToSection(i) {
    scrollTween = gsap.to(window, {
      scrollTo: { y: i * innerHeight, autoKill: false },
      duration: 2,
      onStart: () => {
        observer.disable();
        observer.enable();
      },

      onComplete: () => (scrollTween = null),
      overwrite: true
    });
  }

  panels.forEach((panel, i) => {
    ScrollTrigger.create({
      trigger: panel,
      toggleClass: { targets: panel, className: "active" },
      start: "top bottom",
      end: "+=199%",
      duration: 1000,
      ease: "power1.inOut",
      onToggle: (self) => self.isActive && !scrollTween && goToSection(i)
    });
  });
});
```